# SSIS C# to Generate HTML Email Output from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS Script task that I'd like to use in order to generate the HTML output for an e-mail message.

I have a stored procedure that I pass a `BatchID` to and it spits back the entire HTML message body (it can be upwards for 100K rows). I'd like to take that body and use that to send the e-mail message, using the connection manager `MyConn` (an OLEDB connection).

Is this possible? I don't see why not. Let me know of any issues, since I'm not very used to programming in C#.

Thanks!
-WK

```
string htmlMessageFrom = Dts.Variables["User::EmailFrom"].Value.ToString();
string htmlMessageTo = Dts.Variables["User::EmailTo"].Value.ToString();
string htmlMessageSubject = Dts.Variables["User::EmailSubject"].Value.ToString();
string htmlMessageBody = "";
string smtpServer = Dts.Variables["User::EmailServer"].Value.ToString();
string thisBatchID = "23";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("EmailOutput");

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
cn = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["MyConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)) as SqlConnection);
string SQLQuery = "EXEC dbo.sp_SendHTMLEmailOutput @BatchID";

cn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery,cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchID",thisBatchID);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

try 
{
    while (sdr.Read())) 
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(sdr[0]);
    }
}
finally 
{
    sdr.Close();
    cn.Close();
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
{
    htmlMessageBody = htmlMessageBody + string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, dr[0]);
}

// From,To,Subject,Body,IsHTMLFormatted,ServerName
SendMailMesssage(htmlMessageFrom,htmlMessageTo,htmlMessageSubject,htmlMessageBody, true, smtpServer);
```

Comment: You should see whether you have, or can have, db_mail enabled on your server. Makes this type of thing trivial

Comment: Please include definition of "SendMailMesssage" method.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). What is the correct data type of the `@BatchID` parameter on `dbo.sp_SendHTMLEmailOutput`? Is it coincidentally `nvarchar(2)`?

Comment: If you're expecting 100K rows to be returned consider using a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the `htmlMessageBody` rather than heap-thrashing with `htmlMessageBody = htmlMessageBody + aLittleBitMore`. That operation could also be done inside the SqlDataReader's while loop instead of loading all of the results into a data table (in memory) and iterating over its rows.

Comment: DBMail is not an option with the current implementation....   @batchID is a bigint... How do I use StringBuilder?